# Email and Textarea Javascript Validation

Tags: javascript, validation, textarea

I am new to web development and am stuck with a portion of my code. I am trying to add JS validation for the comment box but can't seem to figure it out. I would to have an alert that will work for both the email and textarea. Thanks in advance for the help.

Here is the JavaScript I have:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function validateForm()
{
var x=document.forms["myForm"]["email"].value;
var atpos=x.indexOf("@");
var dotpos=x.lastIndexOf(".");
if (atpos<1 || dotpos<atpos+2 || dotpos+2>=x.length)
{
alert("Not a valid e-mail address");
return false;
}
}
</script>
```

And here is the HTML I have:

```
 <div class="input">
    <form name="myForm" action="demo_form.asp" onsubmit="return validateForm();" method="post">

   <p class="label"><h2>First Name:</h2>           
    <input type="text">
   </p>
   <p class="label"><h2>Last Name:</h2>           
    <input type="text">
   </p>
   <p class="label"><h2>City:</h2>            
    <input type="text">
   </p>
   <p class="label"><h2>State:</h2>           
    <input type="text" maxlength="2">
   </p>
   <p class="label"><h2>Phone:</h2>           
    <input type="tel">
   </p>
   <p class="label"><h2>*Email Address:</h2>           
    <input type="email">
   </p>  
   <p class="label"><h2>*Comments:</h2>           
    <textarea id="comments"></textarea>
   </p>  
   <p class="label"><input type="submit"></p>

   <p class="label"><input type="reset"></p>
    </form>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The validation is working fine. Have you tried adding `return true` at the end of your function?

Comment: The email validation is fine, but when I add a validation for the comment box, it doesn't work.

Comment: What have you tried ? document.getElementById('comments').value is working fine.